# How can I improve performance on my apply() with fuzzy matching statement

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I've written a function called muzz that leverages the fuzzywuzzy module to 'merge' two pandas dataframes.  Works great, but the performance is pretty bad on larger frames.  Please take a look at my apply() that does the extracting/scoring and let me know if you have any ideas that could speed it up.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import fuzzywuzzy as fw
```

Create a frame of raw data

```
dfRaw = pd.DataFrame({'City': {0: u'St Louis',
                      1: 'Omaha',
                      2: 'Chicogo',
                      3: 'Kansas  city',
                      4: 'Des Moine'},
                      'State' : {0: 'MO', 1: 'NE', 2 : 'IL', 3 : 'MO', 4 : 'IA'}})
```

Which yields

```
City    State
0   St Louis    MO
1   Omaha   NE
2   Chicogo IL
3   Kansas city MO
4   Des Moine   IA
```

Then a frame that represents the good data that we want to look up

```
dfLocations = pd.DataFrame({'City': {0: 'Saint Louis',
                          1: u'Omaha',
                          2: u'Chicago',
                          3: u'Kansas City',
                          4: u'Des Moines'},
                         'State' : {0: 'MO', 1: 'NE', 2 : 'IL', 
                                   3 : 'KS', 4 : 'IA'},
                          u'Zip': {0: '63201', 1: '68104', 2: '60290', 
                                   3: '68101', 4: '50301'}})
```

Which yields

```
    City    State   Zip
0   Saint Louis MO  63201
1   Omaha   NE  68104
2   Chicago IL  60290
3   Kansas City KS  68101
4   Des Moines  IA  50301
```

and now the muzz function.  EDIT: Added choices= right[match_col_name] line and used choices in the apply per Brenbarn suggestion.  I also, per Brenbarn suggestion, ran some tests with the extractOne() without the apply and it it appears to be the bottleneck.  Maybe there's a faster way to do the fuzzy matching?

```
 def muzz(left, right, on, match_col_name='match_on',score_col_name='score_match',
     right_suffix='_match', score_cutoff=80):  

     right[match_col_name] = np.sum(right[on],axis=1)
     choices= right[match_col_name] 

     ###The offending statement### 
     left[[match_col_name,score_col_name]] = 
         pd.Series(np.sum(left[on],axis=1)).apply(lambda x : pd.Series(
         fw.process.extractOne(x,choices,score_cutoff=score_cutoff))) 

     dfTemp = pd.merge(left,right,how='left',on=match_col_name,suffixes=('',right_suffix))         
     return dfTemp.drop(match_col_name, axis=1)
```

Calling muzz

```
muzz(dfRaw.copy(),dfLocations,on=['City','State'], score_cutoff=85)
```

Which yields

```
    City        State   score_match City_match  State_match Zip
0   St Louis    MO      87          Saint Louis MO          63201
1   Omaha       NE      100         Omaha       NE          68104
2   Chicogo     IL      89          Chicago     IL          60290
3   Kansas city MO      NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   Des Moine   IA      96          Des Moines  IA          50301
```

Comment: One possibility is to pull the `right[match_col_name]` outside of the `apply`, so that you don't recalculate it every time.  You should try profiling your code and testing it with different inputs to see if the bottleneck is really in the apply or in the fuzzy matching itself.

Comment: @BrenBarn I don't think I'm tracking you.  I'm just passing a Series(right[match_col_name]) as the choices parameter for the extractOne() function

Comment: Yes, but that is inside the function you apply, which is called once for each element in the series you apply it on.  Your code retrieves `right[match_col_name]` repeatedly, once for each element in the Series.  If you extract this once to a variable and then use the variable in the call, you will avoid all those redundant lookups.

Comment: Ok, gotcha.  I'll give it a go